# Применить css стиль ко всем элементом, а потом откатить это?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Допустим нужно применить css стиль ко всем элементам

```
*{
        overflow-y: visible !important;
 }
```

Чтобы все элементы с прокруткой раскрылись. Затем страница преобразовывается в PDF, а затем нужно вернуть всё обратно как было. 
Это как нибудь можно сделать?

Comment: Можно. Создаете стиль, пишите правило, добавляете. Потом стиль удаляете.

Comment: Как на счет сделать селектор `.pdf-print *`, и цеплять класс `pdf-print` к body или другому блоку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Создаете тег style, пишите правило CSS, добавляете его. Потом тег style удаляете.

```js
var styleExpand = null;

function expandAll() {
  if (styleExpand)
    return;
  styleExpand = document.createElement('style');
  styleExpand.innerHTML = `*{ overflow: visible!important; }`;
  document.body.appendChild(styleExpand);
}

function collapseAll() {
  if (styleExpand) {
    document.body.removeChild(styleExpand);
    styleExpand = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.content-scroll,
.content-visible,
.content-hidden,
.content-auto {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.content-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-visible {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="expandAll()">
Expand
</button>
<button onclick="collapseAll()">
Collapse
</button>
<div class="content-scroll">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus atque autem ducimus facilis fugit, incidunt nam natus, neque praesentium, quidem repellendus sed similique veritatis. Atque ducimus ipsa natus optio similique?</div>

<div class="content-hidden">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus atque autem ducimus facilis fugit, incidunt nam natus, neque praesentium, quidem repellendus sed similique veritatis. Atque ducimus ipsa natus optio similique?</div>

<div class="content-auto">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus atque autem ducimus facilis fugit, incidunt nam natus, neque praesentium, quidem repellendus sed similique veritatis. Atque ducimus ipsa natus optio similique?</div>

<div class="content-visible">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus atque autem ducimus facilis fugit, incidunt nam natus, neque praesentium, quidem repellendus sed similique veritatis. Atque ducimus ipsa natus optio similique?
</div>
```